# Complex analysis - Path independence - condition

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm currently studying for an upcoming exam and our teacher gave us some old exam papers to practice.
And I'm stuck on one of the problems one particular exam paper had.

> Let $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be curves in $D$, which have the same starting point and end point. Formulate a condition, which implies the path independence of line integrals:
>
> $$\int_{\Gamma_1}f(z)dz=\int_{\Gamma_2}f(z)dz$$ .

I have never dealt with this type of problem before. I don't even know what the condition should be based upon.

Comment: The curve realized by following $\Gamma_1$ and then following $-\Gamma_2$ i.e., the path that reverses the orientation of $\Gamma_2$ gives a closed loop.  By Cauchy's theorem, integrating $f$ along this path is zero, as long as the interior of the curve belongs to the domain of holomorphy of $f$.  On the other hand, this integral is precisely the difference of the two integrals in your problem.

Comment: This question is quite vague: $f = 0$ is one condition.